# Mips and cisc assembly langue

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, cycle

does anyone have a simple program with source code run in both assembly langue mips and cisc to explan mips run with less cpu cycle than cisc ?

simple program do not require large one

thank you

Comment: i live in vietnam so my english skill is not really good, i tried searching but can not find anything

Comment: Why do you think mips would run it in less cycles?

Comment: "run with less cpu cycle" -- MIPS instructions are very basic and thus use a lot less CPU cycle, however, you need more instructions to do the same work as CISC, meaning that you need more source code. So often it is not really faster in the end.

Comment: @AlexisWilke can you give me a small demo or a very small source code for this, i really need it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be the comparing two strings against each others:

MIPS

```
; string pointers in $a0 and $a1
more:
  ld $r0,($a0)
  ld $r1,($a1)
  add 1, $a0
  add 1, $a1
  cmp $r0,$0
  je eos
  cmp $r1,$0
  je eos
  cmp $r0,$r1
  je more
eos:
  cmp $r0, $r1
; cmp result defines whether a0 < a1, a0 == a1, a0 > a1
```

CISC (Intel)

```
; start with strings in edi and esi
more:
  cmps (edi), (esi)
  loopnz more
; cmps result defines whether a0 < a1, a0 == a1, a0 > a1
```

I do not guarantee the validity of this code. However, we can see that the CISC does the same thing as the MIPS in 2 instructions (although initialization may require more code in CISC...). However, they are likely taking about the same amount of time.

Comment: I don't think they would take the same time, `cmps` would probably be optimized?

Comment: `cmps` is generally slow... it anyway has to do the same work overall, but may be able to work faster as it can do the two add 100% in parallel. However, the Intel processors have a FLAGS register that can also cause delays (especially for `inc` and `dec`).